# Start RTSP server on Linux with USB Web-cam source

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-streaming, vlc, rtsp

I would like to write a script that runs the RTSP server on a PC with Linux, using ffmpeg, gstreamer, or other media framework.

- Video source: Web camera connected via USB to PC.
- Provide the ability to view the video stream using VLC or another RTSP client.
- Dump traffic using tcpdump

What have I done for now:
streamed the USB camera to a rtsp server by using ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -input_format h264 -timestamps abs -video_size hd720 -i /dev/video0 -c:v copy -c:a none -f rtsp rtsp://10.52.9.104:45002/cameraTx1
```

What to do next? Is it possible to make some bush-script for it?